# How can I extend elements on divA to divB but not divC?

Tags: css, html

I created three divs for the web, left, centre and right.
However, I want to create a section where the content would cross left and centre but not right. I searched for similar method but all I could find is to set position:absolute. Then the content would cross the right div as well and is not what I want. Could anyone please help?

Comment: if you separate left from center. There aren't many choices. You can only do it by tweeking it to position:absolute(left part). You would have to divide it in 2 blocks in order to make it work. Block 1 would be divided again in left and center and Block 2 would be the right section. I hope i understood you correctly :)

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have to create divs specifically for this section.

Comment: You can use an absolutely positioned div with a right margin that's as wide as the right column. The question is, how are the widths of your three divs set?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to use the simplest way instead.